# bind function to an element that created by javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to create a calendar with javascript:

i'm create elements by this function:

```
createElem : function (name, attrs){
     var el = document.createElement(name);
     for(var key in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
     }
     return el;
}
```

table :

```
var tb=this.createElem("table", {"class":"p-calendar", id: "p-calendar"});
```

rows and cells :

```
for(var i=2; i<to; i++){
    tb.insertRow(i);
    for(var j=0; j < 7; j++){
       tb.rows[i].insertCell(j);
       .
       .
```

---

so in my loop:

```
tb.rows[i].cells[j].className="day"; // it's work
```

but :

```
tb.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function(){
    tb.rows[i].cells[j].id = "today";
}  // Unable to set property 'id' of undefined or null reference
```

1. **Why does the error?!**
2. **what is best way to bind function to an element that created by
   javascript?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If 'className' works then the latter should also work.

Comment: Todays million dollar advice is -> [Download a DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) !

Comment: its working for me and if not for you i need 2 things the full script for this part and the type of browser u work on

Comment: update : in function `tb.rows[i].cells[j]` is undefined or null!

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** You need a `closure` for your onclick handler.

**Long answer:**
Your indices `i` and `j` are incremented in a `for` loop. Your `onclick` handlers are called way later when you actually click on the element. Guess what's the value of `i` and `j` then. They are out of bounds of the element arrays of `rows` and `cells`. That means every element is using the same values of `i` and `j` and none of them are getting values within the bounds of the element array. You can verify this by logging the values of `i` and `j` within your current `onclick` handler.

**Solution:**

Replace the block:

```
tb.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function(){ ... }
```

with:

```
var getOnclickMethod = function (i, j) {
    var cur_i = i * 1;
    var cur_j = j * 1;
    var callback = function(){
        tb.rows[cur_i].cells[cur_j].id = "today";
    };
    return callback;
};

tb.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = getOnclickMethod(i, j);
```

Comment: i'm changed to `tb.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = getOnclickMethod(tb.rows[i].cells[j]);`

`getOnclickMethod : function(cell){
                    var callback = function(){
                        cell.id = "today";
                    };
                    return callback;
                },`

Comment: what's this `var cur_i = i * 1;`? * 1?

Comment: @mdvlpr Numbers are immutable in JavaScript. This was done just to get a local copy of `i` and not the original `i`.